# Write dynamic filter for Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a small project use .net Core and Entity Framework.

I need implement dynamic filter for `IQueryable<T>`.

I have enums that define operators

```
public enum QueryOperatorEnums
{
   Equal = 0,
   NotEqual = 1,
   Constant = 2,
   LessThan = 3,
   GreaterThan = 4,
   LessThanOrEqual = 5,
   GreaterThanOrEqual = 6,
}
```

And I have an extensions of `IQueryable`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<QueryOperatorEnums, object>> keyValuePairs)
{
    if (keyValuePairs == null)
        return query;

    foreach (var keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(keyValuePair.Key);

        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            var operation = keyValuePair.Value;

            switch (operation.Key)
            {
                case QueryOperatorEnums.Constant:
                    break;

                case QueryOperatorEnums.Equal:
                    query = query.Where(obj => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null).Equals(operation.Value));
                    break;

                case QueryOperatorEnums.GreaterThan:
                    break;

                case QueryOperatorEnums.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    break;

                case QueryOperatorEnums.LessThan:
                    break;

                case QueryOperatorEnums.LessThanOrEqual:
                    break;

                case QueryOperatorEnums.NotEqual:
                   break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return query;
```

}

What can I do to implement for special cases? Because property value is dynamic at run time. I can't detect type to use `<=`, `>=` ...

Thanks for your support

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this. The expression passed to `Where` must be a valid expression that's translatable to SQL. As such, reflection won't work here. If you need to use reflection, then you'll have to call `Where` by reflection as well. Frankly, I don't even see the point of this. It looks like you're trying to abstract the fact that LINQ is being used here, but you're effectively creating your own, less efficient and more convoluted version of LINQ to do so.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes, my requirement is make common sort and filter and using for another model in projects. Have a solution for my requirement, Chris? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Instead of using reflection, I would recommend building plain expressions here. I've written a library to do this: https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq#dynamic-query-filtering--sorting

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, you cannot use reflection.

However, 2 third-party libraries can help you with this

#### LINQ Dynamic

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/

The syntax required is a little bit different from C# but work great. It's the most popular library to do such a thing.

---

#### C# Eval Expression

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [C# Eval Expression](https://eval-expression.net/linq-dynamic)

The library is not free, but you can do pretty much any dynamic LINQ using the same syntax as C#.

So you will be able to build a string to evaluate and the library will do the rest for you.

Here are some example using EF Classic:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/2sAvrj
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/UptHy0

> Has Dynamic linq work with MySql, Sql Server and Postgresql, Jonathan?

Yes, I don't see why it could not work. Under the hood, is generate LINQ expression as you could call by hand.

Comment: @thanks for your support, Has Dynamic linq work with MySql, Sql Server and Postgresql, Jonathan?